# mvc 4 custom format validator does not show error and allows the form to submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following validator for a MVC 4 view

```
    public class IpFormatValidator: ValidationAttribute 
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ValidationResult resp;

            if (value != null)
            {
                string ip ;
                IPAddress noUsed ;

                ip = value.ToString();

                if(IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out noUsed))
                {
                    resp = ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    resp = new ValidationResult("Please enter a valid IP Address.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resp = new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is required");
            }

            return resp;
        }  

    }
```

And in the model I set it to the required field like this

```
    [IpFormatValidator]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IP Address")]
    public String ipAddress { get { return nullOrTrim(this.ipAddressk__BackingField); } set { ipAddressk__BackingField = value.Trim(); } }
```

I have placed a breakpoint in the validator and I have seend that is being called and is returning the expected value but still the form does not show an error when an invalid IP address is typed.

While looking for an answer another post similar to this mention to include this at the end of the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Are you expecting client side validation? If so then you need to implement `IClientValiIdatable` and add include a client side script for the `$.validator.addMethod()` function

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i need client side validation and this is my first MVC4 project, could you point me to a very clear and specific link or example ?

Comment: [This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) gives a good explanation, but in your case it may not be necessary. What does `IPAddress.TryParse()` actually do (and could it be represented in jquery?) Can you not just use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute?

Comment: Well I also thought about RegularExpression for ip address, does that mean that using a [RegularExpression] works with a client-side validation out of the box ?

Comment: Yes, using`[RegularExpression ]` gives you client side validation out of the box. Although I would consider implementing your own (say) `[IPAddress]` (which inherits from `ReqularExpressionAttribute`) if you use it regularly

Comment: @StephenMuecke `        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)",ErrorMessage = "Invalid IP Address")]
        [Display(Name = "IP Address")]
        public String ipAddress { get { return nullOrTrim(this.ipAddressk__BackingField); } set { ipAddressk__BackingField = value.Trim(); } }` works post it as an answer to give you the credits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get client side validation, your attribute must implement `IClientValidatable` and you must include a client side script that adds a method to the client side `$.validator` object.

This article [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) gives some good examples of how to implement it.

However from the comments, you can do this using the built-in `RegularExpressionAttribute` which will give you both server side and client side validation.

```
[RegularExpression("..your regex..",ErrorMessage = "Invalid IP Address")]
public String ipAddress { get; set; }
```

You can also create your own attribute based on `RegularExpressionAttribute`

```
namespace yourProject.Validation
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public class IPAddressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
  {
    public IPAddressAttribute() : base(@"..your regex..")
    {
        // Add default error message
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid IP Address";
    }
  }
}
```

And then register it in the `global.asax.cs` file

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(IPAddressAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

and use it as

```
[IPAddress]
public String ipAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just a side note - if your regex starts with `^` and ends with `$`, then there would be no need for your use of `Trim();` in the property getter and setter